# Pandas Filter and Insert Data with Missing Indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a pandas Dataframe:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'col0' : pd.Series([1,2,3]), 
                    'col1' : pd.Series([4,5,6]), 
                    'col2' : pd.Series([7,8,9])})

foo.index = ['row0', 'row1', 'row2']

foo
      col0  col1  col2
row0     1     4     7
row1     2     5     8
row2     3     6     9
```

**Is it possible to select from the dataframe with some keys that are in the index and some keys that are not in the index, where the selection process fills in missing rows with default values?**

I'm looking for something of the form (note: `'row4'` is not in `foo`):

```
foo.filterWithFillIn(['row0', 'row1', 'row4'], 0)

      col0  col1  col2
row0     1     4     7
row1     2     5     8
row4     0     0     0
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

```
df = foo.reindex(['row0', 'row1', 'row4'], fill_value=0)
print (df)

      col0  col1  col2
row0     1     4     7
row1     2     5     8
row4     0     0     0
```

If use `pandas 0.21.0+` then it is [recommended way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#indexing-with-a-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated):

> Previously, selecting with a list of labels, where one or more labels were missing would always succeed, returning NaN for missing labels. This will now show a `FutureWarning`. In the future this will raise a `KeyError`. This warning will trigger on a DataFrame or a Series for using `.loc[]` or `[[]]` when passing a list-of-labels with at least 1 missing label.

Comment: This can't possibly be the first reindex/fill_value question we've had, can it?

Comment: @DSM - not sure, but I have idea for nice improving answer.